# How can I create an enum column in Supabase?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I want to create an enum column in a Supabase table. Supabase uses Postgres under the hood, so I understand that technically it is possible if I do it manually using SQL. But is there any way I can do it via the frontend in an easier manner?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Supabase engineer here -- Thanks for the query! You are right that Supabase uses Postgres under the hood and that it can be done via the SQL editor on the Supabase dashboard or directly against the database by using `psql`.

To my knowledge we don't have a way of entering enum types via the frontend as of yet. We will relay this piece of feedback to the frontend team though.

Let us know if you have any further questions.

Update: Frontend team has shipped Enums - please check  supabase.com/dashboard/project/_/database/types

Comment: Is there a roadmap when this will come in?

Comment: ^ Wondering this as well! Supabase is fantastic and would love to see this added.

Comment: Hey all,

Thanks for your patience so far - there isn't a roadmap at the moment but the frontend team has noted it in their list of tasks. They'll be be prioritising tasks at the beginning of 2023 and we'll get back to you once we have more details!

Comment: How is it going @JoelLee , still highly interested in the enum feature, kind of essential

Comment: Hey,

Thanks everyone for patiently waiting. Thanks to the frontend team Enums have now landed - feel free to head to https://supabase.com/dashboard/project/_/database/types and give it a spin

Comment: Hey @JoelLee are you guys planning on shipping this to the supabase CLI frontend eventually?

Comment: Hey @vzwick,

Yes we are- should be in the latest update. Let me know if there are any issues

Comment: I had to refresh the page after creating enum types. (I used the frontend, not the SQL editor)

Comment: Newly created enum types didn't appear in the types menu dropdown in real-time after creating them. I had to refresh the page to fix that issue. It will update in real-time if the Supabase team is able to fix it in the future.

Answer (score 9):

I struggled with this a bit (haven't used SQL in years).

Here is how you can do it, by doing it using SQL directly from the **SQL Editor**.

```
CREATE TYPE employment_status_enum AS ENUM (
  'Active',
  'Inactive'
);

ALTER TABLE "employee"
ADD COLUMN employment_status employment_status_enum 
DEFAULT 'Inactive';
```